# What are the Fedora alternatives for apt, /etc/apt/sources.list, add-apt-repository etc?

Tags: fedora

I have been using ubuntu for quite some time. Recently I moved to Fedora to gain some experience. I need to know the alternatoves of apt, /etc/apt/sources.list, and add-apt-repository in fedora.
Also if you can add some more stuff it will be helpful.
thanks all.

Answer (score 4):

The package manager used in Fedora is called DNF — this doesn't stand for anything; it's just a collection of letters used for the prototype and which stuck. (We may eventually go back to using the name and command Yum; stay tuned for future drama. But for now, `dnf`.)

You will find that most things in DNF work basically the same as apt-get:

- instead of `apt-get install package`, do `dnf install package`
- instead of `apt-get upgrade`, do `dnf upgrade`

There is a nice [comparison of various package managers](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/package-management-basics-apt-yum-dnf-pkg) on the Digital Ocean tutorials site. You should also read the [DNF Documentation](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). One particular thing to be aware of is that DNF updates metadata automatically (and by default, also in the background) rather than that being a separate step. Also, DNF is a single tool with plugins, rather than the various-commands-for-various-things approach of APT.

You can find the configuration data for all configured repositories under the directory `/etc/yum.repos.d`, in various `.repo` files, or get a list with

```
dnf repolist
```

New repositories are often added by installing RPM packages which drop a `.repo` file into the right place, but you can also use `dnf config-manager --add-repo=http://example.com/different/repo` if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Yellowdog Updater Modified (command yum, repos: /etc/yum.repos.d/).

Check out the manual page and let us know if you have any specific question.

Comment: no. The DNF is currently used (though with the same old path to the `yum.repos.d` directory.

Answer (score 0):

read this manual
with dnf you can do all you ask for
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF?rd=Dnf

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.